# how to debug a core file without debug symbols

Tags: linux

I have a core file with no debug symbols but while crash there is one more file generated with .debug extension.

I have never used this file. 
Is it possible to debug the core using this .debug file?

Comment: Actually, the debug symbols are provided by the executable file and related shared objects which are loaded into a process.
If the .debug file has a name as your application, it is likely to be a debug build of your program. With debug symbols, lower optimization setting and active tracing code.

Comment: Besides, the debug information is rarely removed completely from executables: the names of functions (and their addresses) usually stay. So you can just try `gdb application application.core` and have a look at the backtrace (`bt`). A look at disassembly is sometimes revealing as well, even if you're not familiar with the machine code of your platform (the symbolic names are symbolic for a reason)